# Is it possible : modify packets with a Proxy server

Tags: windows-7, proxy

Is it possible that set a proxy for windows (7)  and all packets go Through the proxy server ? I mean all packets even  ARP packets !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is take a look at arp spoofing/poisoning basically arp protocol works by machine saying this is my IP address and the router takes note and forwards any packets with this IP to that machine (Mac Address). SO basically you have to send out the arp messages at a faster rate tricking the router  that messages should be bound to your machine and not the actual mac address that IP should belong to.

just to note (arp is a LAN protocol) so if your proxy is not within the the subnet as the machine your presumably attacking their is no way you can get these packets

Comment: Is there any examples in C# for a local proxy server ?

Comment: No idea, I have never written a line of C# ... im sure there is on this thing called google though